# The user has to enter the email twice to get the next message from the bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

I'm writing a bot on aiogram and have a problem.
The user has to enter the number twice to get the next message from the bot.
*Here is the example:*

Bot, [24.06.2023 20:54]
Write email

Рамиль, [24.06.2023 20:54]
@

Рамиль, [24.06.2023 20:54]
@

Bot, [24.06.2023 20:54]
Choose action:

**Here is the code**

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.email)
async def process_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    email=message.text
    if email.startswith("@"):
        await Form.next()
    else:
        await message.answer("Write email pls")
```

What is wrong?

i tried this but it didn't help

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.email)
async def process_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    email=message.text
    if email.startswith("@"):
        await message.answer("Write email plsss")
    else:    
        await Form.next()
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?